# How to cut copper pipes quickly (and cleanly)

Tags: plumbing

Are there tools for cutting copper pipes that work faster than manual tube cutters like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000LDGNCU)? I have the latter type of cutter, and it works fine, but it takes a fair amount of time and effort to cut a pipe with it. I'm assuming there must be tools that work faster but I'm not sure what I'd have to search for because I don't know what they are called.

I know I could always use a reciprocating saw for a fast cut, but I'm looking for something that would be both fast and cut the pipe cleanly.

Comment: Is your blade sharp? Is it *not* from Harbor Freight/Canadian Tire/eBay/Amazon/Ali?

Comment: Those tube cutters work well with practice, but also they gently "round" the cut edge so that the pipe goes into the fitting easier... A pipe with a square cut end always tends to bind at some point...

Comment: I always find this type of pipe cutter much faster as there is no adjusting of the cutting wheel necessary - it is built-in... see https://www.screwfix.com/p/rothenberger-22mm-automatic-copper-pipe-cutter/24477

Comment: I'm with Solar Mike. I've had one of those tools for years and always found it quick and easy to use.

Comment: it is possible that you are not using the cutter correctly ..

Answer (score 6):

A compact miter saw with an appropriate blade would make quick work of things. You'd still have to clean up the cuts to eliminate burrs.

You could also use a circular saw, but you'd want to take care to keep your cuts square.

Most plumbers don't want to lug that stuff around the jobsite, though.  (Even compact cordless circular saws are not something that fits in a tool belt). Once you get skilled with a tubing cutter it's a matter of about 10 seconds, even with 3/4" or larger pipe. You aren't going to reduce that enough with power tools to net much time savings.

Answer (score 6):

The pipe cutter in your illustration is small, and intended for cutting pipes in tight locations.  Notice that the ad is labelled "close quarters".

[image: compact cutter]

If you are using it for cutting new pipe, perhaps that's why you find it takes "time and effort".

[Normal pipe cutters](https://www.amazon.ca/Ridgid-Tools-32920-16-Inch-Conduit/dp/B00018AFG0/) are much larger and provide much better leverage and control:

[image: large pipe cutter]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specialty tool, they have cordless pipe cutters.  They work a lot like the manual type, but are driven with an electric motor.

[image]

[Milwaukee M12 tubing cutter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-M12-12-Volt-Lithium-Ion-Cordless-Copper-Tubing-Cutter-Tool-Only-2471-20/202196530)

There are several brands and sold at home stores and online, the above is just one common example.

If you're cutting a lot of pipe, they can be a big time saver.  They make clean cuts and are very portable.